# I try to call a custom phtml in category backend

Tags: magento2, category, phtml

I created a new phtl file in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/fronted/templates/prodcut/list_rent.phtml` and i want to call it from my category backend/layout updates but it dosen't work.
Now that category take the list.phtml from exact same path as list_rent.phtml, and a want to change list.phtml with list_rent.phtml

Can anyone have a idea?[image: trying to call list_rent.phtml]

Comment: You can not change the Magento core

Answer (score 0):

Access path `app/design/Package/Theme` in this path create folders `Magento_Catalog/template/product` and put `list_rent.phtml` file in folder created

Comment: i try  to call this phtml only for one type of category. the default i want to be list.phtml

Comment: call this phtml from admin like you in print screen, but the phtml file you put in current theme

Comment: it dosen't work

Comment: <referenceBlock name='category.products.list'>
    <action method='setTemplate'>
        <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Magento_Catalog::product/list_rent.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>